# verify text presence and visibility without locator in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have written code to verify text and visibility WITHOUT locator. please suggest guys, is this correct method?

If there is any alternate method then your suggestion is appreciated.

```
public class TextVisibility {

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
public static String baseUrl = "website url";
public String client = "your search string";

public void visibilityOfText(){

    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
    boolean feedBack = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).getText().contains(client);
    boolean feedbackVisible = element.isDisplayed();
    if(feedBack==true){
        System.out.println(client+ "is present");
        if(feedbackVisible==true){
            System.out.println(client+ "is visible");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(client+ "is not visible");
        }

    }
    else{
        System.out.println(client+ "is not present");

    }

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();

}

}
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, did you get what they said in your yesterday's question? You accepted the answer and not using it? Do you realize `element.isDisplayed()` checks the visibility of the body element, not the text?

Comment: //this will show whether my text present or not (without using locator)
boolean feedBack = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).getText().contains(client);
// this will return whether present text is visible or not (without using locator)
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
boolean feedbackVisible = element.isDisplayed();

Comment: WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));

<element>  will extract all elements inside body rit? then if body is visible then why not content inside body is visible?

Comment: my main motto is to verify whether text is present+visible without using locator. it help me to write test script before website design is ready.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it little bit better. I will skip questioning why would you want doing it and assume you just need to do it.

So. The flaw is in this line:

```
boolean feedBack = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).getText().contains(client);
```

because the text can in theory be something which is not on the page and then you will get `NoSuchElementException`

So better approach would be

```
//skipping initialization part
try{
  boolean feedBack = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).getText().contains(client);
  boolean feedbackVisible = element.isDisplayed();
} catch (NoSuchElementException e){
   boolean feedback = false;
   boolean feedbackVisible = false;
 }

if(feedBack==true){
    System.out.println(client+ "is present");
    if(feedbackVisible==true){
        System.out.println(client+ "is visible");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(client+ "is not visible");
    }

}
else{
    System.out.println(client+ "is not present");

}

driver.close();
driver.quit();

}

}
```